# Locate, Substring query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to pull the data from between 2 string points in mysql, my example script would be

'otherdata&p1=textneeded&otherdata'

I need to pull the "textneeded" bit, "P1=" is the start position and will only appear once within the string but the "&" sign can appear multiples times.  If there is nothing between these 2 points just return a blank.  Where I have put otherdata, this can be a varying number of things on either end of the points I am trying to extract the data from.  I am no expert at all on mysql so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can use SUBSTRING_INDEX function

Comment: Hi Zaynul, I did look at this but wont this only look for the last occurrence of the "&" sign, and work left from that?  As I mentioned in my original query there may be multiple & signs to the right after the once that I am concerned with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use MySQL's [locate()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) function to get the position of `p1=` substring and then the position of the next `&` and use substr() to extract the string between the two. `+3` and `-3` are to compensate for the length of `p1=`:

```
set @s='otherdata&p1=textneeded&otherdata';
select substr(@s,locate('p1=',@s)+3,locate('&',@s,locate('p1=',@s))-locate('p1=',@s)-3)
```

Comment: That works, great, I was sort of getting there but couldn't work out how to locate the next "&" thanks very much!